# is there a way of making sure a command is called when the button is clicked no matter what happens after the initial click?

Tags: wpf

At the moment the command works fine if you click and release on the button without moving the mouse. My issue is that it won't work if you click on the button and move the mouse(even if the mouse remains over the button) before releasing.

Comment: You should post some code... But try using the MouseDown (or MouseLeftbuttonDown) event instead of the Click event on the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the ClickMode property of the button as "Press" to get your expected result. ClickMode="Press"

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. It all works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

*My issue is that it won't work if you click on the button and move the mouse(even if the mouse remains over the button) before releasing.*

I think you can do this, in this way:

1. Use **Mouse.MouseDownEvent** to register **a Mouse.MouseMoveEvent**, so if the user moves his mouse, it will be fired your custom MouseMoveEvent.
2. In your custom MouseMoveEvent you enable a flag, because the user move his mouse.
3. You can use **a custom Mouse.MouseLeaveEvent** and check if the flag is disable, in this case you do whatever you want because the user doesn't have moved his mouse.